# Responsive lightbox module for drupal

Tags: 7, theming

Are there any responsive lightbox options for drupal? There are plenty of lightboxes that support fixed widths?

Are there currently any that are designed for mobile in mind?

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://drupal.org/node/1630630 , however the lightbox2 works well in the mobile, are you using static height and width for the lightbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using flexbox.

Reveal in the  Zurb Foundation theme is another option.

Answer (score 0):

[Lightbox2 Swipe Gestures Support](https://drupal.org/project/lightbox2_swipe) Adds swipe gesture support for Lightbox2. This makes a lot of sense on mobile or responsive pages, because the "Next" an "Prev" Buttons are only visible on hover.

> Adds swipe gesture support to the well known Lightbox2 module for
>   mobiles. Just swipe left or right on galleries to show the previous or
>   next element!